# Issues with Lerch Phi and Abel-Plana formula branch cuts & integral divergence

Tags: numerical-methods

### Introduction

I have taken the approach of using the Abel-Plana formula to evaluate the Lerch Phi as follows:

$$
\Phi(z,s,a) = \frac{1}{2 a^s} + \frac{(-\log(z))^{s-1}}{z^a} \Gamma(1-s, -a \log(z)) - 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t \log z - s \operatorname{arctan}(t/a)}{(a^2 + t^2)^{s/2} (e^{2 \pi t}-1)} dt
$$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function), this definition is correct iff $\Re(a) > 0$. However, around the branch cut when trying to compute $\Phi(z,1-i,1+i)$, the results as given by the Abel-Plana formula and the results given by my copy of Mathematica 12 differ significantly: $\Phi(-5i, 1-i, 1+i)=-82.99760522684576 + 19.43284862059917i$ according to Abel-Plana, $\Phi(-5i, 1-i, 1+i)=-0.253694504765888 - 0.096558528415123i$ according to Mathematica 12. Curiously, this is not observed for $-4i$. At first I had thought that Wikipedia is once again mistaken and does not list the basics of the domain properly, but the branch cut seems so arbitrary that the $|z|<1$ condition doesn't seem to be the case here. Another speculation was that this happens due to choosing the wrong branch cut in upper incomplete gamma function. I have read about approximating the Lerch Phi using an integral representation with a Hankel contour, but performing contour integration is not particularly convenient in my scenario due to software limitations. The source [seems to have noticed](https://fredrikj.net/blog/2022/02/computing-the-lerch-transcendent/) the problem with this formula as well.

My second thought was the following integral representation, which [according to Wolfram Research](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/07/01/01/01/0002/) converges for $Re(a)>0$, a condition I can easily satisfy:
$$
\Phi (z,s,a)=\int_0^\infty (a+t)^{-s} z^t\ dt - 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\left(t \log\left(z\right)-s \operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)\right)}{\left(a^2+t^2\right)^{0.5s} \left(e^{2\pi i} - 1\right)} dt + \frac{1}{2a^s}
$$

However, this integral does not seem to converge under the specified conditions according to Mathematica 12:

[image: The first integral diverges to infinity.]

Wikipedia specifies a further requirement of $|z|<1$ (so this times Wolfram Research is wrong), but this is not very helpful to me since I am still left without a way to approximate the Lerch Phi function due to problems with incomplete gamma function branch cuts.

For the $z,s,a \in \mathbb{R}$ case I use a method akin to the combined nonlinear-condensation transformation and the Van Wijngaarden transformation to accelerate alternating series as described in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465502006276?via%3Dihub) (with a few corner-case issues in the original paper fixed), however, this method does not seem to generalise to the complex case.

### Question

What technique should I use to approximate the Lerch Phi in the general case (regardless of the bounds of $\Re\ a$) that ideally does not involve contour integration? Or, how could I alter either of the integral formulae to converge to the correct value - perhaps by implementing an approximation to the incomplete gamma function that picks the desired branch cut somehow?